# oracle-java-8 is installed in Ubuntu 12.04 but java -version command doesnot displayed it

Tags: java, ubuntu

I have installed Oracle-Java-8 successfully but when i used the `java -version` command the installed Java version displayed like:

```
Java version "1.7.0_80"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_80-b15)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.80-b11, mixed mode)
```

How can I activate the oracle-java-8?
please guide me.

thanks

Comment: Use `sudo update-alternatives --config java`, see [this answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/184394/370581) on askubuntu.com.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this question is more suited for askubuntu.com and has already been [answered](http://askubuntu.com/a/184394/370581) there

Comment: [This might help](http://www.wikihow.com/Install-Oracle-Java-JDK-on-Ubuntu-Linux), i used it too and it works for me.

Comment: check your JAVA_HOME and PATH variable...

Comment: @RobinKrahl I agree on that, see here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/315646/update-java-alternatives-vs-update-alternatives-config-java

Comment: Although this site is about tooling as well, the best information should indeed be on the OS site; it's much more likely to be correct and up-to-date on those sites.